# How to Update the series (content & length) based on the value of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance, series

There is a dataframe as :

[image: Initial Image]

It is required to be converted into:

[image: Resultant Image]

The dataframe does not have any column name and it is indexed based.

Is there any way to do that efficiently? Kindly help, as I am new into Pandas.

Thanks.

The code I tried is:

```
for i, row in temp_store.iterrows():
    if int(row[1]) < 8:
        print('i : ', i, ': Row: ', row[1], " ::: ", row[int(row[1]) + 2])
        last_column_of_df[i] = row[int(row[1]) + 3]
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  last_column_of_df[i] = row[int(row[1]) + 3]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data as plain text: `print(temp_store.iloc[31:38])`

Comment: `    0316  8  05  21  68  09 21.1 21.2  00  6f
31  0140  8  00  00  00  00   0a   21  2c  27
32  0370  8  00  20  00  00   00   00  00  00
33  043f  8  00  40  60  ff   7e   d0  08  00
34  0440  8  ff  00  00  00   ff   d0  08  00
35  05f0  2  01  00   R
36  018f  8  fe  5b  00  00   00   3c  00  00
37  0260  8  19  21  22  30   08   8e  6d  18`     @Corralien

Comment: I don't know how do you read your file but if you use `read_xxx`, you should use `header=None` because your column header looks like data. `0316 8 05 21 68 09 21.1 21.2 00 6f`

Comment: The CSV file from which I am reading data contains rows of variable length (max = 12, min = 2), so using `header=None` leads to error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3080194, saw 12`

Comment: Can you share your csv file or data are confidential?

Comment: Data is from this GDrive link: `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EBR8M_OXh7TBympzpaB0c0COHgq8vaoT` and Dataset is `DoS_dataset.csv` and `gear_dataset.csv`